# Meteor convert document _id to String/or int

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, web-applications

Good evening, 
I'm using meteor to write a vocab app. So I'm using my function inputVocab to save my vocabs in a Collection. That works. But now i would like to create some kind of "connection" between these two vocabs and save this connection in another database (collection). This "connectionobject" should contain two ids, the ids of the documents.
So i though that i can call the method inputVocab as a parameter of createConnectionObject like that:

```
createConnectionObject(collection, inputVocab(collection, vokabel, sprache), inputVocab(collection, vokabel, sprache), typ);
```

I tried it but there was the fallowing error:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
function inputVocab(collection, vokabel, sprache){
    var id = collection.insert({
        vocab: vokabel,
        language: sprache
    });
    console.log("Gespeichert " + vokabel + " " + sprache);

    return id;
}

function createConnectionObject(collection, idOne, idTwo, typ){
    var idCon = collection.insert({
        type: typ, 
        referenc1: idOne, 
        referenc2: idTwo, 
        amountConnections: 2
    });
}
```

So i searched and found a post where somebody said that to avoid this problem, i've to convert the id to a String or Int but how do i do this or is there a better solution

In addition, the code is running on the client

Comment: Try calling the two `inputVocab` functions separately before calling `createConnectionOb`. This is not a data type issue.

Comment: Ans then save them in 2 variables ?

 var id1 = inputVocab(VocabList, vocabel1, sprache1);
        var id2 = inputVocab(VocabList, vocabel2, sprache2);
                
        createConnectionObject(ConnectionList, id1, id2, vocabs);

Still same mistake

Comment: Where does the error occur now?

Comment: Still in the  JavaScript-Console

Comment: Is `collection` the actual collection reference or just the `String` name of the collection?

Comment: What is the type of `typ`? I suspect that it is not EJSON-serializable, thus causing the error.